# Azure service fabric reliable collection cleanup

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

As SF Reliable collection has bounded memory ,  Collections on a given machine are bounded by the amount of available memory or the amount of available disk space on a node, whichever is lower.

I got to know that Reliable collection is not a cache and does not have  expiration or eviction policies. You cannot insert an item into a reliable collection and give it an expiry time eg. 1 hour from now.

As the memory is limited , is there any better pattern to clean-up items in Reliable collection?

I am not planning to use external distributed cache. 
Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

You could probably run a background worker using [RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.runtime.statelessservice.runasync) to do cache eviction.

But if you need a cache, you can also look into running a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview) with [Redis](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/redis/) on your cluster. Redis can be configured to run '[high available](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)' if needed.